# How to open file with custom extension on android 11 via action open document

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent, mime-types

How i can open file with my extension settings. Framework see this file,but i can't open it. when i set mime_type */* all ok,but it allow to open all file types,but i want to open only .settings file extansion. Thanks everybody for the help.

```
   Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
   i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
   i.putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true).putExtra("android.provider.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true).putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES,new String[] {"text/settings"});
   i.setType("text/settings");
startActivityForResult(i,1);
```

Comment: Sorry, not possible.

Comment: @blackapps i reported issue on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/231704900

Comment: You could better ask for a selectExtension() and/or selectExtensions() function if you want to open your custom extension. Mime types are terrible.

Comment: @blackapps Can you write this idea to my created issue.